# How to deploy git hub pull request at arbitrary url from jenkins?

Tags: github, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, pull-request

I have a git hub pull request raised which I can build using properties from pipeline in Jenkins. 
However, I also want that same pull request gets deployed using kubernetes through jenkins.
I have already API for same application, deployed to specified path in **Ingress.yaml** file which I don't want to change. Only I want to create new path, test the pull request and then delete once it is merged.

Is it possible using job variables in Jenkins to achieve so?

Comment: What does the jenkins pipeline look like? If that pipeline updates the deployment with the new parameters then it will change the specified path in ingress.yaml.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Andrei. Can you please help me out with an example  of what you mentioned above? Also, the pipeline is normal with stages to build and deploy using helm chart.

Comment: with helm chart, we can use `--set` parameters which will do the needful. Hoping to achieve same from pipeline parameters.

Comment: if your deploy stage is using "helm update <deployment>" then it will change the path to your app when you build with parameters. If there is a logic like: if no deployment exists use "helm install" else use "helm update" then you can build with job variables using --set parameters. But to be sure you can test it and rollback if the path is changed

Comment: in my opinion is better to have 2 jenkins jobs, one that deploys on qa/prod/stagging and one that is used for pull request automation. And in your pull request automation job you can build and deploy (with helm install ...), run your tests and delete the deployment at the end.

Comment: yes 2 different jobs makes sense. Thank you for your help @AndreiStoicescu